# Animated short film about an alley cat visiting his former home

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation, drama, short-films

I cannot for the life of me find one of my favourite (albeit depressing) animated shorts. The film features a cat wondering an abandoned (burnt out) mansion, and imagining the building when it was still full of warmth and life.

The music, a moving classical piece, forms the basis for the animation, with the cat at times lost in blissful memories and at others being snapped back to reality when it tries to walk on a floor that has long since collapsed or otherwise interact with the past.

The film ends with the cat fading away like one of the memories it just experienced, and a wide shot of the abandoned ruin of the home that was. The animation style places it before the year 2000, featuring hand-drawn and coloured imagery. I would guess that the film is older than the 1990s but may be wrong. As for country of origin, the lack of dialogue makes it difficult to place, but I would say based on the style and tone that it is either European or from an English-speaking country.

I would be immensely grateful if someone could identify this film, and even more so if they could please link to it.

Comment: This reminds me of a Garfield episode where he gets lost in the city and stumbles into an abandoned restaurant. Inside he meets his mother and has flashbacks of his life as a kitten and being fed lasagna.

Answer (score 3):

That is one one of the scenes in [Allegro Non Troppo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegro_Non_Troppo), (1976), a parody of Walt Disney's [Fantasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantasia_(1940_film)).  Like Fantasia, it features classical pieces set to color animation.  The one with the cat is

> [Sibelius's Valse triste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valse_triste_(Sibelius)), a cat wanders in the ruins of a large house.
>   The cat remembers the life that used to fill the house when it was
>   occupied. Eventually all of these images fade away, as does the
>   cat, just before the ruins are demolished.

The short can be viewed [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xc1ifm_allegro-no-troppo-valse-triste-1977_shortfilms).